# AspectJ IntelliJ - No matching factory method found: factory method 'aspectOf()'

Tags: spring, maven, intellij-idea, aspectj

So I have a spring / maven project which i've recently moved over from eclipse to intellij. Mainly this was due to Juno giving me performance grief. Anyway when I make in intellij It seems that the aspects aren't weaved, I can't work out why though. It works perfectly from command line so I suspect its something to do with my setup in intellij.

Additionally i've started using Scala, but i'm not sure that this should interfere ?

I've exhaustively tried various combinations of the aspectJ weaver plugin and the Ajc with no success.

I would like to know exactly how to set it up correctly?

Cheers
Mike.

Answer (score 1):

Which IDEA version do you use? Normally, you don't need AJ Weaver plugin, and AJ Support plugin (bundled) should be able to import Maven project and setup all dependencies correctly (when it's not it should show some warnings).

To start: switch off AJ Weaver, then do Maven | Reimport on project's pom.xml, then make sure Settings | Compiler | Java Compiler is set to Ajc, then make sure Project Structure | Facets have AJ facets with correct aspect path for all modules to be weaved, then rebuild a project.

If this doesn't help please file an issue in a [tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/).

Comment: Yeah the AJ Weaver is a red herring, my first approach was to try, as you suggest, to build using the bundled tools. Idea 12.0.3

Comment: Please track [IDEA-101079](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-101079) for progress.